# rpy2 windows Unable to unlink tempfile

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm using Python 3.3, R-3.0.1,  Win7-64.   I'm getting an "Unable to unlike tempfile" in rpy2.robject (ln 48).  Looking at it, some other process (presumably R) has hold of the file when Python is trying to release it.  It's not a major problem, but it's not clear how I might fix it.

Anyone else seen this?  Ideas?
    --Don

Comment: Please file a bug report on the bitbucket project page for rpy2.