# Import rpy2.robjects gives error

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, bigdata

I have a data which contains 10 millions records. I have an R code which requires to estimate the coefficient of a model using 3000 iterations. Running the R code on this data is very time consuming and sometimes my system got hang. I am using windows 8.1-64 bit version with 4 GB ram.
In order to reduce the time, I want to integrate R with Python. Though I have moderate knowledge in R, but I am completely new in Python. I found out that rpy2 can be used to call R from python (I have python version 3.4.1).
I have done the following:

import rpy2

import rpy2.robjects as robjects

But is is giving the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface__init__.py", line 29, in 
    0, win32con.KEY_QUERY_VALUE )
pywintypes.error: (2, 'RegOpenKeyEx', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects__init__.py", line 15, in 
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface__init__.py", line 32, in 
    except ImportError(ie):
NameError: name 'ie' is not defined

I cannot understand why I am getting error. How to overcome the error.

But, if I do the following, its working:

from rpy2 import *

It will be very helpful if someone explain how to call R from Python elaborately and give a solution for my problem.
Any other solution regarding how to run big data in R with lesser time will also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would python help optimize this?

Comment: Is there any alternate method which can handle big data in R?

Comment: Do you have [defined the environmental variables](https://github.com/lgautier/rpy2/blob/master/INSTALL_WINDOWS#L14)?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem due to the fact my environment was not properly setup and `import win32api` would raise `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`. In fixed it by adding to my `PATH` the folder containing my `python.exe`.

Note that the exception `NameError: name 'ie' is not defined` is a bug in rpy2 that hides the actual exception, triggered by the failure to import either `win32api` or `win32con`.

However I had another exception afterwards (`RuntimeError: R_HOME not defined`), so I ended up adding a `R_HOME` variable (= `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2`) as suggested in another answer (and I'm also having the `Unable to unlink tempfile` warning, which I guess has not been fixed yet, see [rpy2 windows Unable to unlink tempfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992115/rpy2-windows-unable-to-unlink-tempfile) and https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/132/rpy2-windows-unable-to-unlink-tempfile)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the exact same problem running in Win7 x64 with Python 2.7 and R3.1.1

1) install pywin32: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/
2) Add the environment variable R_HOME: [path to R, not /Rx.x/bin]

I still have an issue with "Unable to unlink tempfile" at import time, but I was able to complete some of the demos outlined here: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html