# importing rpy2.objects gives error: unable to initialize the JiT

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I am trying to incorporate some R code in the python environment. I imported `rpy2` package successfully. However, I get the error when I try to import `rpy2.objects`

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

I get the below error

```
Error in glue(.Internal(R.home()), "library", "base", "R", "base", sep = 
.Platform$file.sep) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(paste) which requires 3
Error: could not find function "attach"
Error: object '.ArgsEnv' not found
Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT
Restarting kernel...
```

I found some of the related questions in SE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077831/cannot-import-rpy2-robjects-but-can-import-rpy2) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918899/load-ext-rpy2-ipython-fatal-error-unable-to-initialize-the-jit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073584/import-rpy2-robjects-gives-error). But, none of them seem to work.

Comment: I am trying to load packages such as ```pandas2ri```, ```anndata2ri```. But, it gives error.

Answer (score 2):

Form what I've gathered: if you have R installed on your machine it will avtomatically use the system's installation of R instead of the version `rpy2` requires. To omit that I just added

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Users/<your user>/anaconda3/envs/<env name>/lib/R'
```

before I imported anything from `rpy2`. If it doesn't work, you may have to uninstall R from your machine completely.

Answer (score 0):

Or your could use:

```
os.environ["R_HOME"] = f"{os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']}\\Lib\\R"
```